# Python package install in docker ignores code changes

Tags: python, docker, setuptools

I install my custom Python package inside a docker container using setuptools (setup.py). My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ...

COPY . /tmp/python_package/
RUN pip install -r /python_package/requirements.txt

RUN sh /tmp/python_package/install_script.sh
```

Contents of install_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd tmp/python_package/
python setup.py install
python setup.py clean --all
```

Now when my code changes I would like that to be reflected in the image.

Right now I am only able to achieve this after:

1. Deleting all volumes
2. Deleting all images
3. docker system prune

A simple docker-compose build or just re-running the install script doesnt work (code changes are being ignored)

Comment: Should your `pip install -r /python_package/requirements.txt` be `pip install -r /tmp/python_package/requirements.txt`? Also, you could consider during development to [use a volume mount](https://vsupalov.com/rebuilding-docker-image-development/) for your "live" code (hence not needing to rebuild as often until you need to test a release image)

Comment: How are you rebuilding and running the image?  The "deleting all volumes" mount (and @Sparrow1029's comment) suggest to me you might be overwriting the image content with a volume mount; that can lead to changes in the image being totally ignored, and I'd suggest removing any volume mount over `/tmp/python_package` or `/python_package` if you have that.  (Use a non-Docker Python virtual environment for day-to-day development.)

Comment: Yes, i had a conceptual gap here. It seems like i dont need to run setup.py at all and i should rather just use a volume to mirror the code into the image. It works now. Thank you for your answers as well!